# MST Kruskal's algorithm in Python

Tags: python, performance, graph

I have this code for finding MST for undirected weighted graph, currently works for graphs with maximum 10 vertices. How can I update the code to scale for larger graphs?

```
# Python program for Kruskal's algorithm to find Minimum Spanning Tree
# of a given connected, undirected and weighted graph

from collections import defaultdict

#Class to represent a graph
class Graph:

    def __init__(self,vertices):
        self.V= vertices #No. of vertices
        self.graph = [] # default dictionary to store graph


    # function to add an edge to graph
    def addEdge(self,u,v,w):
        self.graph.append([u,v,w])

    # A utility function to find set of an element i
    # (uses path compression technique)
    def find(self, parent, i):
        if parent[i] == i:
            return i
        return self.find(parent, parent[i])

    # A function that does union of two sets of x and y
    # (uses union by rank)
    def union(self, parent, rank, x, y):
        xroot = self.find(parent, x)
        yroot = self.find(parent, y)

        # Attach smaller rank tree under root of high rank tree
        # (Union by Rank)
        if rank[xroot] < rank[yroot]:
            parent[xroot] = yroot
        elif rank[xroot] > rank[yroot]:
            parent[yroot] = xroot
        #If ranks are same, then make one as root and increment
        # its rank by one
        else :
            parent[yroot] = xroot
            rank[xroot] += 1

    # The main function to construct MST using Kruskal's algorithm
    def KruskalMST(self):

        result =[] #This will store the resultant MST

        i = 0 # An index variable, used for sorted edges
        e = 0 # An index variable, used for result[]

        #Step 1:  Sort all the edges in non-decreasing order of their
        # weight.  If we are not allowed to change the given graph, we
        # can create a copy of graph
        self.graph =  sorted(self.graph,key=lambda item: item[2])
        #print self.graph

        parent = [] ; rank = []

        # Create V subsets with single elements
        for node in range(self.V):
            parent.append(node)
            rank.append(0)

        # Number of edges to be taken is equal to V-1
        while e < self.V -1 :

            # Step 2: Pick the smallest edge and increment the index
            # for next iteration
            u,v,w =  self.graph[i]
            i = i + 1
            x = self.find(parent, u)
            y = self.find(parent ,v)

            # If including this edge does't cause cycle, include it
            # in result and increment the index of result for next edge
            if x != y:
                e = e + 1  
                result.append([u,v,w])
                self.union(parent, rank, x, y)          
            # Else discard the edge

        # print the contents of result[] to display the built MST
        print "Following are the edges in the constructed MST"
        for u,v,weight  in result:
            #print str(u) + " -- " + str(v) + " == " + str(weight)
            print ("%d -- %d == %d" % (u,v,weight))
 g = Graph(14)
 g.addEdge(0, 1, 7)
 g.addEdge(0, 3, 3)
 g.addEdge(1, 2, 3)
 g.addEdge(1, 4, 2)
 g.addEdge(2, 5, 2)
 g.addEdge(3, 4, 3)
 g.addEdge(3, 6, 2)
 g.addEdge(4, 5, 5)
 g.addEdge(4, 7, 7)
 g.addEdge(5, 8, 3)
 g.addEdge(6, 7, 3)
 g.addEdge(6, 9, 1)
 g.addEdge(7, 8, 7)
 g.addEdge(7, 10, 3)
 g.addEdge(9, 12, 4)
 g.addEdge(9, 10, 1)
 g.addEdge(10, 11, 6)
 g.addEdge(10, 13, 7)
 g.addEdge(11, 12, 6)
 g.addEdge(11, 14, 2)
 g.addEdge(12, 13, 4)
 g.addEdge(13, 14, 5)

 g.KruskalMST()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you assume this code is limited to 10 vertices? This code comes from: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-2-kruskals-minimum-spanning-tree-mst/

But you have an error in use:

```
 g = Graph(14)
```

Defines a graph with `14` vertices but then you used `0-14` which is `15` vertices. Either use:

```
 g = Graph(15)
```

Or remove all the edges with vertex `14`.